# Add css margin if not first word of a line

Tags: html, css

I have one span within another.

```
<span class="main">Text <span class="hlgt">Highlighted text</span> More text</span>
```

I want to add a left margin to the inner hltg span only if the first word of that span is not at the beginning of a line and a right margin only if it's last word is not the last word of the line.

```
.hlgt {
    background-color: #FFED00;
    margin: 0px 10px
}
.main {
    color:#3930FF;
}
```

What do I need to add to my css to do that?

Here's some screenshot of what I mean as I see from the answers and comments that the above is not clear.

When hltg is not at the begin of the line (i.e. wide screen) I want the margins.

[image: hltg is not at the begin of the line]
<sub>(source: [creative-scripts.com](http://creative-scripts.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Screen-Shot-2015-11-19-at-13.45.07-copy.jpg))</sub>

When hltg is not at the begin of the line (i.e. narrow screen) I current still get the margins. (I do not want the left one in this case).

[narrow screen puts in unwanted margins] http://creative-scripts.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Screen-Shot-2015-11-19-at-13.45.35-copy.jpg](http://creative-scripts.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Screen-Shot-2015-11-19-at-13.45.35-copy.jpg)

I want the narrow screen to look like this.

[narrow screen no margin added] http://creative-scripts.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Screen-Shot-2015-11-19-at-13.46.11-copy.jpg](http://creative-scripts.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Screen-Shot-2015-11-19-at-13.46.11-copy.jpg)

Although I have written **narrow** and **wide** screens the terms are just fitted to the included very small text.  It could very well be that with a long text the wider screen will have the hltg in at the beginning of the line and the narrower screen the hlgt will be in the middle.  Just adding this point for extra clarification.

Thanks

Comment: used to this .hlgt{margin-left:10px;}

Comment: I can't figure out what you really need. Anyway, You could do something with Jquery by testing the text of your span : `if($(".hlgt").text() == ...)`

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question to clarify what I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution how you could solve that. (Added the extra wrapper to show how it behaves when line breaks)

**Update**

The gap between the "More text" and "Text" is now solved.

```css
.wrapper { width: 50%; background-color: #ddd; }

.main {
  color:#3930FF;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.hlgt {
  background-color: #FFED00;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.hlgt + .main {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="main">Text </span><span class="hlgt">Highlighted text</span><span class="main"> More text</span>      
  <span class="main">Text </span><span class="hlgt">Highlighted text</span><span class="main"> More text</span>      
  <span class="main">Text </span><span class="hlgt">Highlighted text</span><span class="main"> More text</span>      
</div>
```

**Update 2**

You can actually do like this as well and get the same result with even less markup.

```css
.wrapper { width: 50%; background-color: #ddd; }

.main {
  color:#3930FF;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.hlgt {
  background-color: #FFED00;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <span class="main">Text </span>
  <span class="hlgt">Highlighted text</span>
  <span class="main"> More text
  
  Text </span>
  <span class="hlgt">Highlighted text</span>
  <span class="main"> More text
  
  Text </span>
  <span class="hlgt">Highlighted text</span>
  <span class="main"> More text</span>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had a quick look at it but will hopefully look over it some more in the next couple of days to see if it answers the question

Comment: @Trevor Of course, and just drop me a note if you have further questions.

Comment: Hi LGSon I added my own answer based on yours, If you update your answer to reflect the added points I'll which you probably assumed as obvious I'll erase my answer and mark yours as correct (presuming that I haven't been up voted on the answer too much ;-)  In the meantime I've mark mine as correct.  Either way thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Trevor Updated to my final solution/answer where the gap between "More text" and "Text" is solved as well, so now you can delete yours and accept/upvote mine :)

Comment: I like your first updated method. Marked your answer as correct but left mine in tacked.  I would add CSS values `.hlgt::before {font-size:0px;content:" ";}` and `.hlgt::after {font-size:0px;content:" ";}` and remove the spaces in the HTML that immediately precede and follow the hlgt class i.e. the space after the word Text and before word More, that way the indent is going to be precisely as desired and not adjusted by the space width.  I suggest you update your answer accordingly, but the choice is yours!  I think that this has answered the question really well. Thanks again.

Comment: I came up with a new method which I preferred so I marked it as correct, sorry about that.

Comment: @Trevor No need to be sorry, it's your call, and I prefer mine as it hasn't the issue your new approach has.

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial solution for your question, this is only able to put a `margin-left` on the element when it is not the first word of the line. Using the same HTML markup in your question, you can add this to your CSS:

```
.main {
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -10px;
    color:#3930FF;
}

.main::first-letter {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.hlgt {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-indent: 0;
    background-color: #FFED00;
}
```

This uses a combination of the `first-letter` pseudo-element and the `text-indent` rule to achieve this effect.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arnellebalane/z3a4kr8p/) to see it work :)

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question to clarify what I am after.

Comment: Oh so that's what you mean. Hmm, that's more challenging, I'll see what I can come up with :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, short and sweet!

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.hlgt {
  background-color: #FFED00;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.hlgt::before,
.hlgt::after {
  font-size: 0px;
  content: " ";
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    Text<span class="hlgt">Highlighted text</span> More text
    Text<span class="hlgt">Highlighted text</span> More text
    Text<span class="hlgt">Highlighted text</span> More text
    Text<span class="hlgt">Highlighted text</span> More text
    Text<span class="hlgt">Highlighted text</span> More text
    Text<span class="hlgt">Highlighted text</span> More text
</div>
```

Comment: I updated your answer (and gave you +1) since you gave me the idea. This solution still suffer from the fact that the words doesn't make use of the space available, but has one interesting benefit, much simpler (and shorter) markup, so if you want to change back again, I don't blame you :)

Answer (score -1):

You could either do it by using the `margin-left: 10px` statement or, if you wish to use your current notation, you can do `margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px`.

The way `margin` works in CSS is it applies the margins clockwise as you go around the element - the first amount is `margin-top`, second is `margin-right`, third is `margin-bottom`, and fourth is `margin-left` so, in your case, you'd want a `margin` with a value of `0px 0px 0px 10px` to get the `margin-left` effect you were going for.

Have a play around [here](http://codepen.io/ollyjohn/pen/vNPawJ) if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question to clarify what I am after.