# How to increase margins around a word except at the edges of a line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using `<code>` with extra CSS.  I'd like to increase the left/right margins around

```css
code {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
This word is a <code>reserved</code> word.
```

That works fine usually, but if the word is at the beginning of a line, it has the awkward extra margin to the left that I don't want.  Example:

```css
code {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
This word is a <br><code>reserved</code> word.
```

To be clear, the `<br>` was only for the above example... I don't know when the `<code>` is at the beginning of the line, it depends on how it is folded (for a given window width).

CSS `word-spacing` seems like it could be the fix here, but it appears only to be inter-word spacing, so it doesn't work.

Is there a way to accomplish this using CSS?

Comment: CSS also has letter-spacing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add css margin if not first word of a line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800423/add-css-margin-if-not-first-word-of-a-line)

Comment: I think the CSS rules based on line positioning might be a bit easier if, rather than insert `<br>` tags, you separated paragraphs with `<p>` so that it would always begin an element.

Comment: @Katana314 Can you give an example of how that would solve it?

Comment: @LGSon I *think* that would let you use :first-child rules on it and specify that if it's at the beginning of a paragraph, it should have no margin.

Comment: @Katana314 I can't see how that could work, as you never know where inside the paragraph the _reserved_ word is and therefore can't determine if it is in the beginning of a new line or not. If you could provide a sample so we can see how you think would be great.

Comment: @LGSon Never mind. You're correct, that would be a problem regardless.

Comment: @LGSon: Given the OP's question history I think it's safe to assume they already know how to accept answers so you don't have to remind them. If there are no accepted answers, chances are there simply isn't a satisfactory answer yet and it would be a disservice to future readers to choose an answer at this time.

Comment: @BoltClock You are very right ... I was to quick adding that comment, I normally do check if they have a history of accepting, and if so, I often ask if it helped instead. Thank you for notifying.

Comment: @Brian Did my answer help? If not, is there something I can address to make it work for you.

Comment: I have the same problem for my `userContent.css`. I’m already styling a site with `div.status-content code:not(:-moz-first-node)` for `margin-left` and last for `margin-right`, but if the paragraph/`li`/… has line breaks just before a `code` tag it still looks ugly.

Answer (score 4):

I can only find <strike>2</strike> 3 ways to solve this, unless you want a script running through the text and count lines, and that is by wrapping the rest of the text too,

```css
span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
code {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span>This word is a </span><code>reserved</code><span> word.
This word is a <br></span><code>reserved</code><span> word.
This word is a </span><code>reserved</code><span> word.</span>
```

or each word directly in front of the reserved word.

```css
span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
code {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
This word is <span> a </span><code>reserved</code> word.
This word is <span> a </span><br><code>reserved</code> word.
This word is <span> a </span><code>reserved</code> word.
```

If the in front word's element would differ frequently (like `span`, `b`, `i`), here is a CSS rule variant to cover that.

```css
code {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
*:not(br) + code {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
This word is <span> a </span><code>reserved</code> word.
This word is <i> a </i><br><code>reserved</code> word.
This word is <b> a </b><code>reserved</code> word.
```

---

Here is yet another way, though it as a minor flaw where it won't break the line properly, as the reserved word need to be without a space in the markup to the closest word in front. It does have another benefit though, of a minimal markup.

```css
code {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
code:before,
code:after {
  font-size: 0px;
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
This word is a<code>reserved</code> word.
This word is a<code>reserved</code> word.
This word is a<code>reserved</code> word.
This word is a<code>reserved</code> word.
This word is a<code>reserved</code> word.
This word is a<code>reserved</code> word.
```

Comment: This is the only answer that I can see that would work, so plus one for that.  I unfortunately find it too painful to use (that is, to write the HTML as you specified).  Instead, I will either do a JS solution which isn't hard, or just punt on this as not important enough for me to implement.  Thanks!

Comment: @Brian In this fiddle demo is yet another way, though it as a minor flaw where it won't break the line properly, as the reserved word need to be without a space in the markup to the closest word in front. https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/n7r8wwze/1/ As it let you keep a simple markup, let me know if this would be an acceptable solution and I add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this using pure CSS.

First the Firefox-only solution:

```html
<html><head>
 <title>MWE</title>
 <style type="text/css"><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/
  code:not(:-moz-first-node):before {
    content:" ";
    font-size:40pt;
    line-height:0px;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
  }
  code:not(:-moz-last-node):after {
    content:" ";
    font-size:40pt;
    line-height:0px;
  }
 /*]]>*/--></style>
</head><body>
<p>This word is a <code>reserved</code> word. […] This word is a <code>reserved</code> word.</p>
</body></html>
```

(where `[…]` is the same sentence copied a hundred times)

This adds spacing before and after (tweak the `font-size` and (if needed) `font-face` settings to change the size) while making use of the fact that the spaces are kept out of the line. Kudos to [this answer by Alohci](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16978305/2171120) for that part.

It also makes use of a Firefox-only property to *not* do this if the element is the first element; otherwise, `<li><code>foo</code>…` would look weird (thanks to [WesJ’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54350959/2171120)).

If you need portability to not-Firefox, simply drop that, i.e. use `code:before` and `code:after` selectors instead. In that case, you’ll have to take care to not begin a sentence (`p`, `li`, …) with a `<code>` tag, or use extra mechanisms (classes, elements, JS, …) to apply suitable workarounds.

Answer (score -1):

Use the immediate sibling selector.

```css
code {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
br+code{
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
   
This word is a <br><code>reserved</code> word.
```

Comment: Perhaps unclear - the <br> was only for example... OP don't know when the <code> is at the beginning of the line, it depends on how it is folded.